# Why is not needed to declare the begining of a transaction?

Tags: sql

The title explains everything. Why is not needed to declare the begining of a transaction, but is needed to explicitly declare their end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is possible to determine when a transaction must be started - when the first statement is executed (there is a possibility to explicitly `BEGIN` it, since you might want to enter it before any statements are ready to be run).

But it's not obvious when you're done. You may finish the logical unit of work after this query, or 10 hours and million more queries after.